# How to set command button instead of content control in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some trouble here and i try to find any resources but i don't think i can understand it because it is too vague for me since i am using activeX command button.

i have code such as these.

```
Private Sub NewPage_Click()
    Select Case ContentControl.Title
        Case "NewPage"
            Dim oCC As Range
            Set oCC = ContentControl.Range
            oCC.Start = oCC.Start - 1
            oCC.Collapse 1
            Application.Templates(ThisDocument.FullName). _
                    BuildingBlockEntries("QuestionPage").Insert _
                    Where:=oCC, _
                    RichText:=True
End Sub
```

When i run these, i got an error on `ContentControl`. It is because i am using activeX command button but i don't know how to change these codes to command button.

Can anyone help?

Notes: Once again,  if you noticed that, NewPage_Click() is a command button. Now the Select Case is for content control. What i wanna do is to change the Select Case ContentControl.Title to Select Case CommandButton or like so. Since right now, it is looking for contentcontrol named NewPage, however i want to set it to command button. It is just that i don't know and found how to change the "ContentControl.Title" and "ContentControl.Range" for ActiveX CommandButton.

I want the select case code to execute the code for Command_Button (NewPage_Click()).

Comment: Which `ContentControl`? Which error? Please clarify your question.

Comment: sorry if im not being clear here. If you noticed that, NewPage_Click() is a command button. Now the Select Case is content control. What i wanna do is to change the content control to Select Case Command Button or so. Since right now, it is looking for contentcontrol named NewPage, however i want to set it to command button. It is just that i don't know and found how to change the "ContentControl.Title" and "ContentControl.Range" to ActiveX CommandButton

Comment: I want the select case code to run based on command button which is NewPage_Click() itself, not ContentControl.Title or ContentControl.Range

Comment: You should [edit] your post to improve it by including this information. Comments aren't ideal for this.